# How to complete this recursion in Scala?

Tags: scala

im trying to make a method that sums rational numbers, but im stuck on one part.

```
class Rational( x: Int , y: Int ) {
    private def gcd( a: Int , b: Int ) : Int = if ( b == 0) a else gcd( b, a % b)
            private val g = gcd( x, y)
            def numer = x / g
            def denom = y / g


            def +(r: Rational) =
            new Rational(numer * r.denom + r.numer * denom,
                    denom * r.denom)
    override def toString = numer+"/"+denom

def sum (f: Rational => Rational)(a: Rational, b: Rational): Rational = 
      f(a) + sum(f)(a + 1, b)
```

I am having trouble figuring out (a + 1, b) in my sum part, i get an error that says type mismatch Int , i think it because its expecting a rational number, but i dont know how to convert or replace that 1.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a + operator for `Rational`, but not for int. You also need to define the exit point for the recursion, probably when `a > b`?

Here's one take, although you'll need to define an operator `>` for Rationals. You might also consider two `object` singletons to represent 0 and 1:

```
def sum (f: Rational => Rational)(a: Rational, b: Rational): Rational = 
   if (a > b) // You'll need to define this
      new Rational(0,1) // Exit point for recursion
   else
      f(a) + sum(f)(a + new Rational(1, 1), b)
```

**Edit**
Re: How do you call this?
`f` is any function which takes a `Rational`, and returns a `Rational`.
Here's an example of the identity lambda - so basically all we are doing is adding all the integers from 1 through 5:

```
 override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val rat = new Rational(1,1)
    val theSum = rat.sum(x => x)(new Rational(1,1), new Rational(5,1))
    println(theSum)
 }
```

Here's an [IdeOne snippet](http://ideone.com/zfj9hw) showing the result.

Comment: alright i defined > as. def >(that: Rational) = numer * that.denom > that.numer * denom.  which i believe works. now the embarassing part lol. i dont know how to test this. i try to use x.sum(f)(a, b) , im assuming the a and b are the 2 rationals , but it asks me for a function which i am not sure what goes there.

Comment: @zerocool18 Apols - I was AFK for a few hours - updated with sample. I guess its moot whether `sum` in its current incarnation belongs as an instance method on `Rational`, given that it doesn't use any of the fields ...

Comment: i see now!!! but when i test it i get a "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError " error , which means someting i wrong with the recursion , so close lol

Comment: also , im supposed to get this , An example: if a =1/2 and b = 4/5, then you should calculate f(1/2)+f(2/3)+f(2/4)+ f(3/4)+ f(3/5)+f(4/5)

Comment: The stackoverflow will be because the exit criteria aren't being met, e.g. you're summing from 5 to 2, and 5,6,7,8... will stackoverflow before the int overflows. For the new summation criteria, you'll need to change the algorithm from just +1 to instead increase the numerator or denominator